# Растяжение изображения

Tags: java, изображения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким(и) способом можно обработать готовое изображение что бы растянув/сжав придать ему форму разностороннего четырёхугольника (или хотябы трапеции). Прямоугольник - не то. Не обрезать, а именно растянуть как от перспективы. Причём для таких форматов: jpg, gif и видео. Не обязательно, что бы одним методом сразу все три формата.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например можно брать картинку и отрисовывать её в канвас с нужными параметрами и сохранить результат в файл (или в буфер...). Видео и гифки - то же самое, только с каждым кадром в отдельности.

Comment: А SurfaceView справится со всем этим?

Comment: @AndreiAndreiPedash справится.